# Instagram feed endpoint returns no results if min_id / max_id cursor points to a post that does not belong in feed

Tags: api, pagination, instagram

To reproduce:

1. Go to Instagram API console
2. Call the API endpoint for a user's home feed, see results
3. Take the id of the last post in the results and use it as a max_id, still see results
4. Go to https://instagram.com and find that post
5. Unfollow the account that created that post
6. Try to repeat step 3
7. Get no results

Expected outcome:

Still see results even if that post is removed from the feed

---

API endpoint for a user's home feed (https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed):

```
  "user_has_liked": false,
  "id": "688020827340746959_651838531",
  "user":  {
    "username": "underground_nyc",
    "website": "",
    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_651838531_75sq_1389924363.jpg",
    "full_name": "Clifton",
    "bio": "",
    "id": "651838531"
  }
```

id of last post in results: 
**688020827340746959_651838531**

Find that post on http://instagram.com and unfollow the account with the post so that the post does not show up in home feed anymore.

Call same API endpoint but with the id of that post as the max_id cursor

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?max_id=688020827340746959_651838531

Observe that no results returned

```
{
  "pagination":  {},  
  "meta":  {
  "code": 200
},
  "data":  []
}
```

Instagram should still return results even if the max_id cursor is pointing to a post that does not show up on the feed; it should just return posts with ids smaller than the post. This is very problematic for trying to create an instagram feed and paginate for more results because it's very hard to tell if the user has unfollowed the someone or if there's just no results.

Instagram should either allow for time-based pagination instead of max_id / min_id to allow for more flexibility, or it should provide better error messages so that we know the issue is that the post does not show up on the feed and we can handle the situation better.

Comment: Did you find a way around this? Now I've got to handle this "filtering" on the client-side since min_id doesn't always work. Quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram deprecated /users/self/feed

[Instagram changelog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)